# Android minSdkVersion=3 but app is not availabe for android 1.5 devices from Android Market?

Tags: android

In AndroidManifest.xml file I have set -

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:largeScreens="false" android:anyDensity="false"/>
```

So that app should be available for android 1.5 and higher devices. But I am unable to find this app from Android Market for 1.5 devices. App is available for 1.6 and higher devices.

I am able to install app on 1.5 devices using USB cable and it works fine.

Please explain why the app is not available from market for 1.5 devices.

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing it with a specific 1.5 device? Can you tell us? Maybe it is being filtered not due to API level 1.5 but due to the smallScreen or anyDensity constraint

Comment: No we are testing it on a device having normal screen size/density.

Answer (score 1):

I always add:

```
<supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
```

And this seems to work.
supports-screens is only implemented in SDK4, so I think you should add that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the  fields in the AndroidManifest.xml that is preventing some devices to "see" it in android-market... substituting them with  seems to weak-link it and the application become visible for more devices